# UITableView background Clear with colored cells

Tags: ios, uitableview, uibackgroundcolor

I am wanting to make my tableView background clear, but have the cells still be colored.  This sounds weird, even as I type it, but the reason is that my table view is grouped, but I don't want the header or footer titles with it.  Here are two images, one is when the TableView background is clear and the 2nd when it is set to default.  [image]
[image]
As you can see, when set to default, it adds where the title would normally be.  So, how can I get tableView.backgroundColor clear and cell.backgroundColor to a different color?  I try setting the cell color but it has no effect.

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
```

willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
     {
        [cell setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
     }

Or try this

```
[[UITableViewCell appearance] setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the cell's background color in the `tableView:willDisplayCell:forRowAtIndexPath:` method instead of the `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method.

Answer (score 0):

For the cell colour I found this delegate method worked a treat after the other property calls didn't seem to be working. Change the colour or alpha properties to suit.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

[cell setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithWhite:1 alpha:0.5]];

}
```

Within viewDidLoad, set table colour to clear

```
self.tableview.backgroundColour = [UIColor clearColor];
```

I hope this helps with what you're looking for.

Cheers Jim

Answer (score 0):

you will have far better luck ditching grouped table style and going plain table style with clear color table and cell backgrounds, then add uiimageview with radius corners as background view of your tableview cells. Even better, make a uitableviewcell subclass.

I can't recall why, just remember doing this same thing years ago and having frustration.  maybe things have changed.